# Live listing of tables in a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, that makes a list in a sheet ("Lastkombinationer") of all the tables in another sheet ("A1.6Laster").

1. I have made macros that add and delete tables, so I need a code to
   make the listing live, so that whenever I add/delete a table the
   list is adjusted automatically.
2. Also, the list is ordered from oldest added table to newest added
   table. I need it to be in the order of the table at the top to the
   table furthest down.
3. Finally I would like to exclude a certain table from the list.

Thanks in advance. An answer to any or all of these questions is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Laster()
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim GCell As Range
    SearchText = "Laster"
    Set GCell = Worksheets("Lastkombinationer").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(0)
    Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Lastkombinationer")
    lRow = GCell.Row
        For Each tbl In Worksheets("A1.6Laster").ListObjects
            lRow = lRow + 1
            With wsSummary
                .Cells(lRow, "A") = tbl.Name
            End With
        Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Call your procedure at the end of the add and delete macros.  3) Is it always the same table?

Comment: 1) So this whole code should be copied to the end of the add/delete macros?

3) Yes, always the same table.

Comment: no you can call another routine from within a routine by giving its name: so just put the name "Laster" on a line by itself at the bottom of your add/delete routines (without the speech marks)

Comment: Consider adding some error handling in case SearchText is not found e.g. If Not GCell Is Nothing Then ....

Comment: 3) As it is always the same you could exclude using an if statement.  Ex: `If tbl.Name <> "Exlude-Me" Then .... End If`.  The current lines `LRow = LRow + 1` to `End With` would be placed inside the if statement.

Comment: 2) Sorting in VBA is a pain.  But you could have Excel do it for you!  Using the [macro recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) manually sort in Excel.  Then integrate that code into yours.